# Can't locate XML/XPath.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, xpath, include, centos

I have a `.pl` script in which starts by:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::XPath;
use Getopt::Long;
```

I can't seem to run that via `perl myScript.pl`, having this error:

```
(@INC contains: /usr/share/ /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at most_generic_wrapper.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at myScript.pl line 3.
```

1- I tried to locate the `XPath.pm` file and export that as:

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5/XML/Twig
```

and

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5/XML
```

2- Installed `perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::Parser'`

3- Used -I to explicitly define the path as:

```
perl -I perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::Parser' myScript.pl
```

4- changing the line 3 to `use XML::Twig::XPath;` led to:

```
cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XPathEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available at /usr/share/perl5/XML/Twig/XPath.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/XML/Twig/XPath.pm line 13.`
```

But none of them solved the issue and I keep receiving the same error at line.3.

P.S: Running on `CentOS 6.2`    with the `kernel 2.6.32-358` and `perl --version=v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi`

Any helps would be appreciated,

Comment: Should be `export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5`

Comment: i tried that, didn't work. the same error. `Can't locate XML/XPath.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/share/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at myScript.pl line 3.`

Comment: The earlier version of the post implied `/usr/share/perl5/XML/XPath.pm` existed. `export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5` is not going to help if it doesn't.

Comment: it is existed in that dir and I did `export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5` but without any success

Comment: You also need to have permissions to access it.

Comment: I just check `ls -l /usr/share/perl5/XML/Twig/XPath.pm` and it turned out that I just have the access to read it `-rw-r--r--`, is that OK ?

Comment: Yes, but wrong file. I said `/usr/share/perl5/XML/XPath.pm`

Comment: (You probably don't have to set `PERL5LIB`. I think your `perl` already looks in `/usr/share/perl5`.)

Comment: OK. I got it :) so apparently the problem should be solved by installing `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::XPath`

Comment: I can confirm that the problem solved by installing `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::XPath`. thanks again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your title says XML::XPath can't be found, but your question indicates you tried to install XML::Parser. Did you try to install XML::XPath?
2. From `man perlrun`: "If PERL5LIB is not defined, PERLLIB". You seem to have tried setting PERLIB5 (notice the spelling difference: the var is PERL5LIB (or PERLLIB), not PERLIB5).
3. From `man perlrun`: "PERL5LIB -- A list of directories in which to look for Perl library files before looking in the standard library and the current directory." You seem to have tried setting it to the full path to a .pm file, rather than a directory.
4. The file you assigned would be XML::Twig::XPath, not XML::XPath; those are two different Perl modules.

**Edit:** After looking at your revised question:

1. I'm not sure if your script requires XML::Twig::XPath or XML::XPath, or if either one can provide the API you need. However, XML::Twig::XPath seems to depend on XML::XPath so you will need XML::XPath no matter what, and it looks like XML::XPath is not installed on your system. I think that's probably the main problem. Please try to install XML::XPath using CPAN.
2. The value of the PERL5LIB variable (or the argument to the -I option) should be the directory that sits at the base of the package-qualified module file. For example, if XML::XPath is located at ~/perl_custom_modules/XML/XPath.pm, then you need to set PERL5LIB (or the -I argument) to ~/perl_custom_modules. The XML directory is part of the package qualification of the module, so does not need to be included in the include path.

Comment: thanks for the answer and sry for y typo! I am revising those now.

Comment: @Amir, why? You didn't address the issue bgoldst raised (You're installing XML::Parser, but it's XML::XPath that's missing.)

Comment: @ikegami, i am on it, since I am not a sudoer, I have asked the admin to install that. I will report the outcome here.

Comment: @Amir, There are ways of installing to your home directory, but since you appear to have a willing admin, let's stick to that.

Comment: @bgoldst, Sounds like he wants XML::Twig::XPath, and that it requires (XML::XPathEngine or) XML::XPath

Comment: @ikegami From my reading of http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm, it looks like if you use XML::Twig::XPath, then it will automatically try to use XML::XPath as its xpath engine.

Comment: actually  with a recent (less than 6 years old I think) version of XML::Twig it will look first for XML::XPathEngine, then, if not available, to XML::XPath